# How to cast a double into std::chrono::milliseconds

Tags: c++, timer, casting, c++-chrono

I am using `boost::asio::steady_timer m_timer` and if I am not mistaken, in order to call `m_timer.expires_after(expiration_time_ms);`, `expiration_time_ms` should be a `std::chrono::milleseconds` variable.

Nevertheless, in my case, I have the expiration time as a `double`. I would like to know if it is possible to cast a double into `std::chrono::milliseconds`

The aim is to call

```cpp
void
setExpirationTime(my_casted_double) {
  boost::asio::steady_timer m_timer;
  m_timer.expires_after(my_casted_double)
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One nice trick is to multiply your values with chrono literals:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

double time = 82.0;
auto t_82ms = time * 1ms;
std::this_thread::sleep_for(t_82ms);
```

It also works the other way around:

```
double time = t_82ms / 1s; // time == 0.082
```

Comment: I have tried your proposal (which seems to be approved by the community), but I am getting the following error:

error: no viable conversion from 'duration<double, [...]>' to 'const duration<long long, [...]>'
        const std::chrono::milliseconds my_time = my_double * 1ms;

Comment: `my_time` should be a `std::chrono::duration` type (or just leave auto)

Comment: @m88 `boost::asio::steady_timer::expires_after` wont accept a floating point duration without an explicit cast

Answer (score 4):

`m_timer.expires_after` will accept any duration which is convertible to `boost::asio::steady_timer::duration` it doesn't need to be `std::chrono::milliseconds` (and if you don't want to discard the fractional milliseconds from your duration you shouldn't be converting to `std::chrono::milliseconds`).

You can convert your `double` into a `std::chrono::duration` as follows:

```
double milliseconds = 0.1;
std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> chrono_milliseconds{ milliseconds };
```

`chrono_milliseconds` can't however be passed automatically into `expires_after` as there is no automatic conversion from floating point durations to integer ones. You can fix this with a `std::chrono::duration_cast`:

```
m_timer.expires_after(
  std::chrono::duration_cast<boost::asio::steady_timer::duration>(chrono_milliseconds));
```

Comment: This is definitely the right answer since I was already dealing with the errors coming from my timer.

Comment: This might be a good place to use `ceil` in place of `duration_cast`.  The difference is that `ceil` will round any fractional milliseconds up to the next whole millisecond instead of down.  This all depends on what you want `expires_after` to do with fractional milliseconds.